# java spring boot fetch values from db before starting up

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I am new to java and spring boot (ard 1 month exp). 
Can anyone tell me how can i load data from memory before starting the application.

Example:

I have info in db say gender

```
TABLE : gender
F : Female
M : Male

TABLE : COUNTRY
1 : US
2 : UK
3 : RUSSIA
```

So before application start i want this data shoulw be fetched from db and load to my application.

I am using java + sprint boot + JPA

Comment: https://medium.com/@dmarko484/spring-boot-startup-init-through-postconstruct-765b5a5c1d29

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest way would be to do it right after the Application starts (in the main method).

```
 public static void main(final String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    context.getBean(YourClass.class).loadFromDatabase(); //Or whatever you want
}
```

I don't know why would you need it before startup. You can also include it in one of the beans (the one that actually needs the data) and use the @PostConstruct method. Or provide an Init method for that bean

Comment: Is application ready event spring seems better option that this ? Also i want this as i am saying db query on real time. Also it will increase the time of first req

Comment: yes it will increase the first request so if you do it in the main method it will work when app is started

Comment: so dont you think event is better  as we can do it just before startuo

Comment: In my opinion it would be the same. Whatever you find more readable and suitable for your goals. Here is an article on the different events in the startup lifecycle: https://springframework.guru/running-code-on-spring-boot-startup you can attach to any of them

Comment: after startup means 1st  few user will get delayed response  and before none

Comment: Yeah if the users start working with that in the split second your appliaction starts but you may consider it part of the application startup. So it hasn't actually started before the data is loaded right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use static block as where you can load.

```
static { // logic to load data from db. }
```